# Find and delete lines in file based on String but keep last occurrence

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Need Help. Ive been searching for a full day not finding a solution specific to what I need.

In a file:

```
Lots
of
other
lines
...
...
# Client=HOSTNAME@ ..........1323    <- Do not include '# Client=HOSTNAME'
# Client=HOSTNAME@ ..........123123  <- Do not include '# Client=HOSTNAME'
Client=hostname1@ ....rndChars.... <- delete line
Client=hostname1@ ....rndChars.... <- delete line
Client=hostname2@ ....rndChars.... <- delete line
Client=hostname2@ ....rndChars.... <- delete line
Client=hostname2@ ....rndChars.... <- keep last occurrence
Client=hostname1@ ....rndChars.... <- keep last occurrence
Client=hostname3@ ....rndChars.... <- delete line
Client=hostname3@ ....rndChars.... <- delete line
Client=hostname3@ ....rndChars.... <- keep last occurrence
...
...
more
lines
```

I need to find all lines matching "Client=" or more and delete the lines Except for the last occurrance. Problem is I never know what the hostname will be.

Output should be:

```
Lots
of
other
lines
...
...
# Client=HOSTNAME@ ..........1323    <- Do not include '# Client=HOSTNAME'
# Client=HOSTNAME@ ..........123123  <- Do not include '# Client=HOSTNAME'
Client=hostname2@ ....rndChars.... <- keep last occurrence
Client=hostname1@ ....rndChars.... <- keep last occurrence
Client=hostname3@ ....rndChars.... <- keep last occurrence
...
...
more
lines
```

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ tac file | awk '/^Client=/{if (seen[$1]++) next} 1' | tac
Lots
of
other
lines
...
...
# Client=HOSTNAME@ ..........1323    <- Do not include '# Client=HOSTNAME'
# Client=HOSTNAME@ ..........123123  <- Do not include '# Client=HOSTNAME'
Client=hostname2@ ....rndChars.... <- keep last occurrence
Client=hostname1@ ....rndChars.... <- keep last occurrence
Client=hostname3@ ....rndChars.... <- keep last occurrence
...
...
more
lines
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue. Read the file twice, keep the last line number per host in a hash table.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $client_re = qr/Client=(.*?)@/;

my $filename = shift;

open my $IN, '<', $filename or die $!;

my %lines;
while(<$IN>) {
    next if /^#/;

    # Overwrite the line number if already present.
    $lines{$1} = $. if /$client_re/;
}

seek $IN, 0, 0;  # Rewind the file handle.
$. = 0;          # Restart the line counter.
while (<$IN>) {
    if (! /^#/ && ( my ($hostname) = /$client_re/ )) {
        print if $lines{$hostname} == $.;  # Only print the stored line.
    } else {
        print;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tac` & `awk`:

```
tac file | awk '/^Client/{ if(!a[$1]){a[$1]++;print};next}1' | tac
```

**Output:**

```
$ tac file | awk '/^Client/{ if(!a[$1]){a[$1]++;print};next}1' | tac
Lots
of
other
lines
...
...
# Client=HOSTNAME@ ..........1323    <- Do not include '# Client=HOSTNAME'
# Client=HOSTNAME@ ..........123123  <- Do not include '# Client=HOSTNAME'
Client=hostname2@ ....rndChars.... <- keep last occurrence
Client=hostname1@ ....rndChars.... <- keep last occurrence
Client=hostname3@ ....rndChars.... <- keep last occurrence
...
...
more
lines
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;:b;s/(.*)(Client=[^@]+\b)[^\n]+\n*(.*\2)/\1\3/;tb' file
```